# Get title and href under nested div using beautifulsoup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract title and href in `<a title="Jon Turner" class="_32mo" href="https://www.facebook.com/jon.turner.7587">` and the text `'Daphne, Alabama'` that is between `<a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Daphne-Alabama/104071176294827">Daphne, Alabama</a>` source which I got from `requests.get`

```
<div class="_3u1 _gli" data-bt="{&quot;id&quot;:610823379,&quot;rank&quot;:5,&quot;abtest_version&quot;:null,&quot;abtest_params&quot;:{&quot;abtest_version&quot;:null,&quot;origin&quot;:&quot;A&quot;,&quot;ranker&quot;:null},&quot;section&quot;:&quot;main_column&quot;,&quot;owner_id&quot;:null,&quot;sub_id&quot;:null,&quot;browse_location&quot;:null,&quot;query_data&quot;:[],&quot;is_headline&quot;:false}" data-ft="{&quot;tn&quot;:&quot;-\\&quot;}">
<div>
<div class="clearfix _ikh">
<div class="_4bl7 _3-90">
<a title="Jon Turner" class="_2ial" aria-label="Jon Turner" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" role="presentation" href="https://www.facebook.com/jon.turner.7587">
<img class="_1glk _6phc img" src="https://scontent-sjc3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/cp0/p74x74/104258995_10157724933523380_6784568501858187427_o.jpg?_nc_cat=111&amp;_nc_sid=dbb9e7&amp;_nc_oc=AQnwXFpW7dNBp-Tnx11O3pHh4-GhD8BxtkQ8tXJFYRmA1UdUET0O4-o8L_f5GOHfEjj5v9hEFvmf5nrX8M7gSibd&amp;_nc_ht=scontent-sjc3-1.xx&amp;oh=e01068610b697b26a26e78e7d6bfe728&amp;oe=5F1938B5" width="72" height="72" alt="Jon Turner">
</a>
</div>

<div class="_4bl9">
<div data-testid="browse-result-content" class="_glj">
<div class="_5aj7">
<div class="_4bl9">
<div class="_gll">
<div class="_ajw">
<div style="-webkit-line-clamp: 2;" class="_52eh _5bcu">
<div>

<a title="Jon Turner" class="_32mo" href="https://www.facebook.com/jon.turner.7587">
<span>Jon Turner</span>
</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="_4bl7">
<div class="_glk">
<a role="button" class="_42ft _4jy0 _4jy3 _517h _51sy" href="https://www.facebook.com/jon.turner.7587/photos" rel="dialog" ajaxify="/ajax/timeline/sign_up_dialog/?next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fjon.turner.7587%2Fphotos&amp;entity_id=610823379&amp;context=see_photos"><i class="_3-8_ img sp_l43kx7Dp4qP sx_b2b580"></i>See Photos
</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div>

<div class="_glm">
<div class="_pac" data-bt="{&quot;ct&quot;:&quot;sub_headers&quot;}">
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Daphne-Alabama/104071176294827">Daphne, Alabama</a>
<div class="_1my"></div></div></div><div class="_glo"></div>
</div>

<div class="_glp"></div>

<div class="_3t0c"></div></div></div></div></div></div>
```

for the first part, I tried using `soup.find_all('a')` but did not return the href I wanted.

Comment: Can you also share the URL you are trying to scrape?

Comment: @AmartyaGaur This is the url: https://www.facebook.com/public/jon-turner, and I am trying to scrape the title, href, and the location/job displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script will get Title and Current city. Also, I put `?locale=en_US` to URL to get only english HTML page, not localized one.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.facebook.com/jon.turner.7587?locale=en_US'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

title = soup.select_one('#fb-timeline-cover-name')
print(title.text if title else '-')

city = soup.select_one('div:contains("Current city"):not(:has(div))')
print(city.find_previous('span').text if city else '-')
```

Prints:

```
Jon Turner
Daphne, Alabama
```

---

EDIT: For `url="https://www.facebook.com/public/jon-turner?locale=en_US"`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.facebook.com/public/jon-turner?locale=en_US'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

for code in soup.select('code'):
    s = BeautifulSoup(code.contents[0], 'html.parser')
    for result in s.select('[data-testid="browse-result-content"]'):
        name = result.select_one('a > span').get_text(strip=True)
        place_work = result.select_one('[data-bt]').get_text(strip=True, separator=' ')
        print(name, place_work)
```

Prints:

```
Jon Turner 
Jon Turner 
Jon Turner 
Jonathan Turner 
Jon Turner Daphne, Alabama
Jon Turner Taylor, Michigan
Jon Turner Volunteer at Disability Allies East Brunswick Chapter
Jon Turner Owner at Turner Guitar Co.
Jon Turner Sales manager at Tim Short Chevrolet of South Williamson
Jon Turner 
Jon Turner electrician/ farm stuff at SEARS
Jon Turner Bradford High School
Jon Turner Cincinnati
Jon Turner 
Jon Turner
```

---

EDIT: To extract `href=` you can do:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.facebook.com/public/jon-turner?locale=en_US'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

for code in soup.select('code'):
    s = BeautifulSoup(code.contents[0], 'html.parser')
    for result in s.select('[data-testid="browse-result-content"]'):
        name = result.select_one('a > span').get_text(strip=True)
        href = result.select_one('a')['href']
        place_work = result.select_one('[data-bt]').get_text(strip=True, separator=' ')
        print('{:<12} {:<60} {}'.format(name, place_work, href))
```

Prints:

```
Jon Turner                                                                https://www.facebook.com/jon.turner.359
Jon Turner                                                                https://www.facebook.com/people/Jon-Turner/100013646792198
Jon Turner   Operation Support Manager at Brammer Buck & Hickman          https://www.facebook.com/jon.turner.96930
Jon Turner                                                                https://www.facebook.com/jon.turner.14855377
Jon Turner   Daphne, Alabama                                              https://www.facebook.com/jon.turner.7587
Jon Turner                                                                https://www.facebook.com/jon.turner.904
Jon Turner                                                                https://www.facebook.com/people/Jon-Turner/100017624107252
Jon Turner   Owner at Turner Guitar Co.                                   https://www.facebook.com/jon.turner.92560
Jon Turner   Sales manager at Tim Short Chevrolet of South Williamson     https://www.facebook.com/jon.turner.5623
Jon Turner                                                                https://www.facebook.com/people/Jon-Turner/100017624107252
Jon Turner   Bradford High School                                         https://www.facebook.com/jon.turner.370
Jon Turner                                                                https://www.facebook.com/jon.turner.758399
Jon Turner   electrician/ farm stuff at SEARS                             https://www.facebook.com/jon.turner.79
Jon Turner   Owner-operator at JT Improvements                            https://www.facebook.com/jon.turner.923724
```

Comment: Hi, the url I am trying to work with is facebook.com/public/jon-turner, where the names have location or work information.

Comment: This works!! Thank you so much!! Looks more complicated than I thought it would be....

Comment: How would I also extract the href? https://www.facebook.com/jon.turner.7587

Answer (score 0):

Though this might not be the best practice, but you could use the parent div with classnames to get the parent and then obtain the required child from that parent div.

This code assumes that you have made the request and stored the `requests.get()` result in a variable named `req_get`.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# perform the http request and get the result html
# assuming your html is in req_get varaible

soup = BeautifulSoup(req_get.content, 'html5lib')
# soup = BeautifulSoup(req_get.content, 'html.parser')

parent = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': '_52eh'})
title = parent.div.a['title']
href = parent.div.a['href']

parent = soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'"_pac'})
location = parent.a.text

print(title)
print(href)
print(location)
```

this should be good enough for a start.

Comment: I am getting None for 'class': '_52eh' -- perhaps it's because the parent is not a div but div style?

Comment: parent = soup.find('div style', attrs={'class': '_52eh _5bcu'}) is not returning anything either.